# Exsheets: improve subquestions scores features using tasks

Tags: exsheets

I have a question that is composed by several subquestions (which is done using `tasks`). I also want to have a table at the end where I have the score for each question. The questions are as follows:

(1) As you can in the MWE, in the final table only appears the score for questions and not subquestions, is there a way to make all them appear?

(2) Also I need to manually sum the values of subquestions and put it in the questions environment (otherwise it would not appear and be summed in the final table), is there a way to grab the score for each subquestion making it appear in the main question?

(3) I am using `marginnote` to put the score as a side note; and I not very happy with that, is there any `exsheets` mechanism to do it better (e.g., like the headings for questions)?

```
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: clean: { files: [ main.aux, main.log, main.out ] }
% arara: preview

\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[pass,showframe]{geometry}

\usepackage{array}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\usepackage[load-headings]{exsheets}
\SetupExSheets{%
    solution/print=true,
    headings=block-wp,
}

\settasks{label=qu.tsk}

\usepackage{marginnote}

\begin{document}

\begin{question}{3.5}

\begin{tasks}
\task \marginnote{\points{1}}%
\blindtext

\task \marginnote{\points{0.5}}%
\blindtext

\task \marginnote{\points{1}}%
\blindtext

\task \marginnote{\points{1}}%
\blindtext
\end{tasks}

\end{question}

\null\vspace*{\fill}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{|l| *{\numberofquestions}{c|} c|}\hline
Question & \ForEachQuestion{\QuestionNumber{#1}\iflastquestion{}{&}} & Total \\\hline
Points & \ForEachQuestion{\GetQuestionProperty{points}{#1}\iflastquestion{}{&}} & \pointssum* \\\hline
Notes & \ForEachQuestion{\iflastquestion{}{&}} & \\\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no automatic solution. You can however define a question property `subpoints` and with a suitable definition of a command `\subpoints` and a suitable built of the grade table we can get maybe something usable. The code below gives the following grade table:

[image]

Questions are entered similar to

```
\begin{question}
  \begin{tasks}
    \task \subpoints{1} \blindtext
    \task \subpoints{0.5} \blindtext
    \task \subpoints{1} \blindtext
    \task \subpoints{1} \blindtext
\end{tasks}
\end{question}
```

Here's the full code:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[pass,showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{marginnote}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\usepackage[load-headings]{exsheets}
\SetupExSheets{
  solution/print = true,
  headings       = block-wp,
}
% this requires version 0.9 of tasks.sty:
\settasks{
  counter-format = qu.tsk ,
  label-width    = 2em
}

\usepackage{etoolbox,expl3,xparse}
\DeclareQuestionProperty{subpoints}
\makeatletter
\ExplSyntaxOn
\fp_new:N \g_cacamailg_subpoints_fp
\seq_new:N \g_cacamailg_tmpa_seq

% the following assumes you're always going to use a {tasks}
% environment for the subquestions
\cs_new_protected:Npn \cacamailg_subpoints:n #1
  {
    \fp_gadd:Nn \g_cacamailg_subpoints_fp { #1 }
    % \@cntfmts@parsed@pattern holds the current {tasks} label:
    \seq_gput_right:Nx \g_cacamailg_tmpa_seq
      { \@cntfmts@parsed@pattern & #1 }
    % \addpoints adds the points to the current question points
    % and the total sum of points:
    \marginnote { \addpoints { #1 } }
    \ignorespaces
  }
\NewDocumentCommand \subpoints { m }
  { \cacamailg_subpoints:n { #1 } }

\cs_generate_variant:Nn \exsheets_set_question_properties:n { x }

% at the end of a {question}:
\AtEndEnvironment{question}
  {
    % are subpoints given?
    \fp_compare:nNnT { \g_cacamailg_subpoints_fp } > { 0 }
      {
        % then build a table of the subpoints to be used in the grade table
        \exsheets_set_question_properties:x
          {
            subpoints =
              {
                \exp_not:N \begin{tabular}[t]{ll}
                  \seq_use:Nnnn \g_cacamailg_tmpa_seq {\\} {\\} {\\}
                \exp_not:N \end{tabular}
              }
          }
        % clear question specific variables:
        \seq_gclear:N \g_cacamailg_tmpa_seq
        \fp_gzero:N \g_cacamailg_subpoints_fp
      }
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{question}
  \begin{tasks}
    \task \subpoints{1} \blindtext
    \task \subpoints{0.5} \blindtext
    \task \subpoints{1} \blindtext
    \task \subpoints{1} \blindtext
\end{tasks}
\end{question}

\begin{question}{2}
  \blindtext
\end{question}

\begin{question}
  \begin{tasks}
    \task \subpoints{0.75} \blindtext
    \task \subpoints{0.75} \blindtext
    \task \subpoints{1.5} \blindtext
\end{tasks}
\end{question}

\null\vspace*{\fill}

\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|}\hline
  Question & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{ Points } & Notes \\ \hline
  \ForEachQuestion{
    \QuestionNumber{#1} &
    \GetQuestionProperty{points}{#1} &
    \GetQuestionProperty{subpoints}{#1} & \\ \hline
  }
  Total  & \multicolumn{2}{l|}{\pointssum* } &\\\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I tested you code and I am very happy with it. However, I think for students it is useful to know the score of a question as a whole even when using tasks and subpoints. As such, I am wondering if it is possible to have that, e.g., in the 1st question of your code without summing it to the total? I am thinking of something like `\currentpointssum*` to sum the inner subpoints of a question specific question (it would be expanded only after the question is finished) and not added to the total `pointssum*`.

Comment: @cacamailg If you use `\points` instead of `\addpoints` in the definition of `\subpoints` the points will not be added, neither to the current question nor to the total sum. It's not clear to me if that is what you want, though....

Comment: I wanted to be able to specify `\begin{question}{<value>}` where the `<value>` is the sum of the scores of subquestions inside that question. Also that `<value>` would be calculated automatically and not added to `pointssum*` (because it is already done by the subquestions).

Comment: @cacamailg `\begin{question}{<value>}` _always_ adds to the total sum. If you want to specify that `\subpoints` should not add the points but only print them which is exactly what I suggested in my other comment

Comment: I understand that. I think I was not clear. Now I just wanted a `<macro>` to automatically calculate `<value>` which is the sum of `\subpoints` so that I could write `\begin{question}{<macro>}` and that would be translated in `\begin{question}{<value>}`.

Comment: I'm afraid that's Not easily possible: subquestions are placed after the question environment parsed it's arguments. One would need a unique macro for each question that grabs the value from the aux file. It's way easier to calculate that yourself