# Exsheets improve final grade table with subquestions

Tags: exsheets

Following the question from here: [Exsheets: improve subquestions scores features using tasks](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/118755/exsheets-improve-subquestions-scores-features-using-tasks). Is it possible to automatically generate a table with the following aspect like:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|l|}
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{Question} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Points} & Notes \\     \hline
1 & 1.1 & 4 & 1   & \\ \cline{2-2} \cline{4-5}
  & 1.2 &   & 1   & \\ \cline{2-2} \cline{4-5}
  & 1.3 &   & 2   & \\ \hline
2 & 2.1 & 3 & 1.5 & \\ \cline{2-2} \cline{4-5}
  & 2.2 &   & 1.5 & \\ \hline
    \multicolumn{2}{|l|}{Total} & \multicolumn{2}{r|}{7} & \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

The code there for the table almost does that, but I think if there was a way to grab properties from subquestions like it is done for questions it would be easier. I am talking about define two new commands `\SubQuestionNumber{#1}` and `\GetQuestionProperty{subpoints}{#1}` (both used inside `\ForEachQuestion{}`), as such `\SubQuestionNumber{#1}` would return the number (label?) of subquestions in each question and `\GetQuestionProperty{subpoints}{#1}` the score for each subquestion.

[image]

Comment: ExSheets does not really know the concept of subquestions like other packages may do. The `tasks` environment we used in the linked question is just a list link environment which is not tied to `exsheets`. We could have an `enumerate` list instead, for instance.

Comment: Do you really _need_ all those lines? If not then the code from the linked question could easily be adapted...

Comment: @cgnieder I understand your first comment. But I think that subquestions would be a valuable feature (implemented with `tasks` or `enumitem`). Regarding the second comment, I wanted to easily divide what is question from what is points and grades; thus I thought of something like in the picture. But I am very open to new thoughts. I tried to play a little with the code in the linked questions, but hadn't done much since I am not used to LaTeX3 syntax.

Comment: I could provide an answer with a table that looks like yours but with less horizontal lines (the subpoints and -numbers would be collected in an additional table for each question). I'm reluctant to add a `subquestions` environment or similar to `exsheets` as I don't want to tie users to one solution or the other. IMHO the current way is more flexible.

Comment: @cgnieder I think such kind of subquestions would be useful, since most of the times in a question you start introducing the question with the background and some parameters and later you ask the real questions. Nevertheless, for me it would be useful to separate the code that enumerates the questions/subquestion and prints the scores of each.

Comment: We shouldn't discuss possibly missing features in the comments. We can do that via email, on the bitbucket site, or in chat if you like

Comment: @cgnieder Ok. Latter, we can discuss it elsewhere. But I don't have an account in bitbucket site. But if you have a away to draw a table similar to mine (even with less lines) I would be interested.

Comment: ok, I'll post something in a while

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can adapt the code from the linked question to get something similar to the table you posted. I commented the code below so it hopefully becomes clear what everything does. It produces this grade table:

[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[pass,showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{array,booktabs}
\usepackage{marginnote}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\usepackage[load-headings]{exsheets}
\SetupExSheets{
  solution/print = true,
  headings       = block-wp,
  counter-format = qu
}
% this requires version 0.9 of tasks.sty:
\settasks{
  counter-format = qu.tsk ,
  label-width    = 2em
}

\usepackage{etoolbox,expl3,xparse}
% declare` subpoints' and `subnumber' properties:
\DeclareQuestionProperty{subpoints}
\DeclareQuestionProperty{subnumber}
% switch to expl3 namespace and make @ a letter:
\makeatletter
\ExplSyntaxOn
% declare a temporary sequence variable for each property:
\seq_new:N \g_cacamailg_subpoints_seq
\seq_new:N \g_cacamailg_subnumber_seq

% the following assumes you're always going to use a {tasks}
% environment for the subquestions
\cs_new_protected:Npn \cacamailg_subpoints:n #1
  {
    % save the points in the one sequence...
    \seq_gput_right:Nx \g_cacamailg_subpoints_seq { #1 }
    % ... and the current current {tasks} label in the other:
    \seq_gput_right:Nx \g_cacamailg_subnumber_seq
      { \@cntfmts@parsed@pattern }
    % \addpoints adds the points to the current question points
    % and the total sum of points:
    \marginnote { \addpoints { #1 } }
    \ignorespaces
  }
\NewDocumentCommand \subpoints { m }
  { \cacamailg_subpoints:n { #1 } }

\cs_generate_variant:Nn \exsheets_set_question_properties:n { x }

% at the end of a {question}:
\AtEndEnvironment{question}
  {
    % are subpoints given?
    \seq_if_empty:NF \g_cacamailg_subpoints_seq
      {
        % then build a table of the subpoints and another one of the subpoints
        % to be used in the grade table later and save them both as question
        % property:
        \exsheets_set_question_properties:x
          {
            subpoints =
              {
                \exp_not:N \begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l@{}}
                  \seq_use:Nnnn \g_cacamailg_subpoints_seq {\\} {\\} {\\}
                \exp_not:N \end{tabular}
              } ,
            subnumber =
              {
                \exp_not:N \begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l@{}}
                  \seq_use:Nnnn \g_cacamailg_subnumber_seq {\\} {\\} {\\}
                \exp_not:N \end{tabular}
              }
          }
      }
    % clear both sequences:
    \seq_gclear:N \g_cacamailg_subpoints_seq
    \seq_gclear:N \g_cacamailg_subnumber_seq
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{question}
  \begin{tasks}
    \task \subpoints{1} \blindtext
    \task \subpoints{0.5} \blindtext
    \task \subpoints{1} \blindtext
    \task \subpoints{1} \blindtext
\end{tasks}
\end{question}

\begin{question}
  \begin{tasks}
    \task \subpoints{0.75} \blindtext
    \task \subpoints{0.75} \blindtext
    \task \subpoints{1.5} \blindtext
\end{tasks}
\end{question}

\null\vspace*{\fill}

\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{|*4{l|}c|}\hline
  \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{Question } & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{ Points } & Notes \\ \hline
  \ForEachQuestion{
    \QuestionNumber{#1} &
    \GetQuestionProperty{subnumber}{#1} &
    \GetQuestionProperty{points}{#1} &
    \GetQuestionProperty{subpoints}{#1} &
    \iflastquestion{}{\tabularnewline\hline}
  }
  \\\hline
  \multicolumn{2}{|l|}{Total}  & \multicolumn{2}{r|}{\pointssum* } &\\\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! With that the table looks much better. I still think it would be a nice feature to add to `exsheets` package.

Comment: I deliberately chose not to add a grade table to `exsheets` but only the means for the users to create one themselves. There are many different layouts one can think of and I do not want to delimit design choices :)

Comment: I didn't mean to add the table as it is, but with `subnumber` and `subpoints` you add me more choices to design a suitable table. So options like `subnumber` and `subpoints` would be nice in the package. This answer can be a starting point :).

Comment: Every user can add as many properties to questions as they like: `\DeclareQuestionProperty{property-I-need}`. There's no need to use `expl3`, either. `etoolbox`' lists for example would work quite as well here...