# xsim: Vertical shifts by using customized points

Tags: vertical-alignment, marginpar, xsim

I changed inside `\DeclareExerciseEnvironmentTemplate{custom}{...}`

`\IfInsideSolutionF{\rule{1.2cm}{1pt}\slash}%`

to

`\IfInsideSolutionF{\noindent\usekomafont{sectioning}\color{pointscolor}}`

and I used a method for calculating sums of points from here https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/494468/46023

why do I get several vertical shifts here?

```
\documentclass[]{scrartcl}
%\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\colorlet{pointscolor}{blue}

\usepackage[showframe,
left=2cm, 
right=4cm,
marginparwidth=2.125cm,
]{geometry}

\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{xsim}
%\xsimsetup{
%%    clear-aux,
%    solution/print          = false,
%    grading-table/template  = default,
%    grading-table/type      = exercise,
%}

\newcounter{expoints}
\newcommand{\addpts}[1]{%
    \addtocounter{expoints}{#1}%
    \SetExpandedExerciseProperty{points}{\theexpoints}%
    \marginpar[]{\color{pointscolor}\points{#1}}%
}
\xsimsetup{
    exercise/pre-hook       ={\setcounter{expoints}{0}}
}

\makeatletter
\DeclareExerciseEnvironmentTemplate{custom}{%
\GetExerciseHeadingF{\subsection*}%
{%
\XSIMmixedcase{\GetExerciseName}\nobreakspace
\GetExerciseProperty{counter}%
\IfInsideSolutionF
{%
\GetExercisePropertyT{subtitle}
{ {\normalfont\itshape\PropertyValue}}%
}%
}
\GetExercisePropertyT{points}
{%
\marginpar
{%
\IfInsideSolutionF{\noindent\usekomafont{sectioning}\color{pointscolor}}% \rule{1.2cm}{1pt}\slash
\printgoal{\PropertyValue}
\GetExercisePropertyT{bonus-points}{~(+\printgoal{\PropertyValue})
}%
~\XSIMtranslate{points}% point-abbr
}%
}%
}
{\par}
\makeatother

\xsimsetup{
  exercise/template = custom ,
  solution/template = custom
}


\begin{document}
%    \gradingtable
    \begin{exercise}[subtitle=aaa]
        \begin{enumerate}
            \item subquestion 1 \addpts{2}
            \item subquestion 2 \addpts{3}
            \item subquestion 3 \addpts{5}
        \end{enumerate}
    \end{exercise}
    \begin{exercise}[points=7]
        another exercise
    \end{exercise}
    \begin{exercise}
        \begin{enumerate}
            \item subquestion 1 \addpts{1}
            \item subquestion 2 \addpts{2}
            \item subquestion 3 \addpts{3}
        \end{enumerate}
    \end{exercise}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Unrelated: the newest version of `xsim` correctly adds the points with `\addpoints` the the sum of points of the exercise, see the discussion here: https://github.com/cgnieder/xsim/issues/58

Comment: @cgnieder Do you mean this is a problem with marginpar not with xsim?

Comment: I do not have an example without that error!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can work around this with a suitable template definition where a) the `\marginpar` is issued before the paragraph of the heading ends and b) its content starts with `\leavevmode` itself (I have not researched why the latter seems to be necessary when colors are in play – BTW: `\usekomafont{sectioning}` issues `\normalcolor`).

Below I also removed the manual calculation of points. It is not necessary any more with an up to date `xsim`.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[
  showframe,
  left=2cm,
  right=4cm,
  marginparwidth=2.125cm
]{geometry}

\usepackage{xsim}
\usepackage{xcolor,needspace}
\colorlet{pointscolor}{blue}

\newcommand*\pointformat{\usekomafont{sectioning}\color{pointscolor}}
\newcommand*\addpts[1]{\marginpar{\leavevmode\pointformat{\addpoints{#1}}}}

\makeatletter
\DeclareExerciseEnvironmentTemplate{custom}
  {%
    \par\vspace{3.25ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}
    \Needspace*{3\baselineskip}%
    \noindent\usekomafont{sectioning}%
      \XSIMmixedcase{\GetExerciseName}\nobreakspace
      \GetExerciseProperty{counter}%
      \IfInsideSolutionF{%
        \GetExercisePropertyT{subtitle}
        { {\normalfont\itshape\PropertyValue}}%
      }%
    \GetExercisePropertyT{points}{%
      \marginpar{%
        \leavevmode\pointformat
        \printgoal{\PropertyValue}%
        \GetExercisePropertyT{bonus-points}{~(+\printgoal{\PropertyValue})}%
        ~\XSIMtranslate{points}%
      }%
    }%
    \par\vspace{1.5ex plus .2ex}
    \normalsize\normalfont
    \@afterindentfalse\@afterheading
  }
  {\par}
\makeatother

\xsimsetup{
  exercise/template = custom ,
  solution/template = custom
}

\begin{document}

\begin{exercise}[subtitle=aaa]
  \begin{enumerate}
    \item subquestion 1 \addpts{2}
    \item subquestion 2 \addpts{3}
    \item subquestion 3 \addpts{5}
  \end{enumerate}
\end{exercise}
\begin{exercise}[points=7]
  another exercise
\end{exercise}
\begin{exercise}
  \begin{enumerate}
    \item subquestion 1 \addpts{1}
    \item subquestion 2 \addpts{2}
    \item subquestion 3 \addpts{3}
  \end{enumerate}
\end{exercise}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: He wants me to install 
`pdftexcmds.sty
infwarerr.sty
ltxcmds.sty`
Ok, why not.    But I do not get the points-sums (10 points and so on) with that code....

Comment: @cis The picture above was created with a complete texlive 2019 updated this morning…

Comment: I did `tlmgr update --all` this afternoon. This was not enough?

Comment: BTW: There occurs no error or something like that. It show simply no point-sums....

Comment: @cis after how many compilations?

Comment: About 3-4 (or uncountable more...) :()

Comment: @cis I just copied my code from above: it gives the picture I posted after two compilations. Maybe you have some local packages interfering or something… does it say `Package: xsim 2020/02/23 v0.18` in your log?

Comment: I have been completely confused, because I have the latest version. But there was a mistake in my file system.    It works! ... fine!

Comment: xsim is a very fine package, by the way.   But hard-boiled to use. ;)
Good written manual, that not copies the line numbers of code-blocks. but you wouldn't have expected otherwise from @cgnieder.